# Access private GKE cluster with public endpoint via Cloud Build worker pools

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been working on setting up an automated deployment flow for my private Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster using Cloud Build worker pools. Initially, I tried the recommended VPC peering and VPN tunnels [approach](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/accessing-private-gke-clusters-with-cloud-build-private-pools) for a completely private GKE cluster, but couldn't get it to work despite multiple attempts spanning a few days.

Now, I've switched to a GKE private cluster with a public endpoint and I'm trying to configure a Cloud Build worker pool following the guidance [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/use-in-private-network#deploying-to-clusters). I've set up the worker pool on the default network, allocated an internal IP range, and established a private service connection. However, I'm still facing issues with accessing the GKE control plane via Cloud Build.

When I authorize all networks (0.0.0.0/0) on my GKE cluster, the build works, but that's not an ideal security practice. I'm struggling to identify the specific IP range that I should whitelist on my GKE cluster to allow my worker pool to perform the deployment. Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't provide clear guidance on this aspect.

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or solutions from the community regarding how to properly authorize the IP range for my Cloud Build worker pool to access the GKE control plane in this setup.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You should only need to allowlist the internal IP range you allocated for your Cloud Build pool

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going back to the initial [approach](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/accessing-private-gke-clusters-with-cloud-build-private-pools) of accessing a completely private GKE cluster via a worker pool and managed to get it to work.

I believe my problem was setting a conflicting CIDR for the worker pool. Specifying `192.168.0.0/24` instead of `192.168.0.0/20` as suggested in the tutorial worked for me.

The original problem of accessing a private GKE cluster with an external endpoint is still unsolved.

I have to say, this is quite a lot of effort to establish access to a private GKE cluster.